# display method in grid is showing the same text in all rows

Tags: join, axapta, sqldatasource, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a very simple display method on a table to display the weekday of a given date:

```
display DateDayName day()
{
    WeekDays    weekday;
    ;
    weekday = dayofwk(this.TransDate);

    return enum2str(weekday);
}
```

but for some reason when I use this method on a grid on a specific form the displayed text uses the first record for all lines in the grid and when a new line is selected the selected line is updated with the correct text and the prevoiusly selected record gets updated with the value of the newly selected record.

[image: Issue image 1]

[image: Issue image 2]

As can be seen, the datasource is linked to another datasource but it looks like it has been set up correctly. I have tried various settings for datasource and linktype but it hasn't helped or changed anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer myself immediately after posting. I was about to try to change the display method to being on the forms datasource instead of being on the table when I found that it was already there with the same name. This was probably causing problems for axapta in choosing which method to read as it is the default place to look for display methods if the datasource is not specified. I simply changed the name of the method on the datasource and all was fine.

Answer (score 2):

You get this when a display method is placed on the form. For display methods, they should be put on the table itself, and should generally be the first place you put such code according to best practices.

I believe the reason it displays the same value for every record is because the record that is being rendered is not what the method is using to lookup the value - the first current selected record is. Additionally, you would see that if you changed the selected record, the value would seem to 'change' unexpectedly. In this case, when you select a new record, the method runs again with the new record as a data source, and AX puts the resulting value in both the previously selected and newly selected records (if I remember correctly).

The easiest way to think about this is that a form will have a table buffer of some size (generally 2+) so it can display all the information for multiple records simultaneously. However, a display method calling the buffer can only refer to a single record at a time, so we need to determine which record that is. On a form, the most intuitive way to determine which record is passed would be the current selected record.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I chose my own answer as it solved the actual problem which basically was that I was unaware that someone else had placed a display method on the form. You do present some good and valuable information, though.